# Why is the border between 23 and 24 black instead of red and how do you fix it?

Tags: css

Below is a screenshot of the page.  There should be a red border between 23 and 24, just like between 30 and 01.  For some reason when there is a class of busy, it changes the border to black, even though dow0 comes after busy in the css file (line 233 vs line 228) and even when dow0 comes after busy in the markup.

Devtools shows both rules as active, but chrome shows the border as black.  Why?

[image: Rendered page layout]

[image: Devtools of the DOM and css rules]

Comment: Try to add !important after red : `border-left:1px solid red !important`. I think "border" is priority to "border-left".

Comment: !important does not change anything.  It shows both rules are active, unlike color in the .JobsSummary td that is struck thru.

Comment: @KevinLabécot `border-left` and `border` have the same precedence. Mark, can you include the relevant code *in* the question please?

Comment: Had the same problem: are the widths of table and/or `thead>th` set? Is the width of table exactly the width of columns? Do you have a fiddle reproducing your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is because square "23" that turns it's right border (left for "24") black again?

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I had to adjust dow6.busy to have a read border and that fixed it.